# Insert into PSQL DB from datetime-local html input

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime, jdbc

I'm unable to get the proper format for the datatime into the insert statement (more of prepared statement).

Input from HTML (as setter) into variable as 'String' -

```
<input  style="border:1px solid grey; width: 100%"  type="datetime-local" id="maintsd" name="maintsd">
```

Setter:

```
  public void setMaintsd(String maintsd) {
        this.maintsd = maintsd;
    }
```

Prepared Statement:

```
 ps.setTimestamp(2, obj_modeSwitch_Bean.getMaintsdI());
```

Setter puts values as  `2020-09-05T23:59`

now the prepared statement doesn't set with setTimeStamp(my function to fetch) OR setDate(func to fetch datetime)

Is there a change in the prepared statement or with the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [`PreparedStatement#setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,%20java.lang.Object))

Given below is an example:

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-09-05T23:59", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
st.setObject(1, ldt);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

In your case, it should be

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(obj_modeSwitch_Bean.getMaintsdI(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
ps.setObjec(2, ldt);
```

Comment: Thanks, Made the changes according to my case that you've provided. Is there's something the PSQL intake and HTML intake differs from the typecase it requires?
Also, java8 vs old version has deprecated anytime dateTime?

Comment: You are most welcome. I strongly recommend you always use the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API as used in this answer. Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.